# Cannot find the text I want to scrape in the Page Source

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Simple question.  Why is it that when I inspect element I see the data I want embedded within the JS tags - but when I go directly to Page Source I do not see it at all?

As an example, basically I am looking to get the description of the eBay listing.  In this case, the text in the body of the listing that reads "BRAND NEW  Factory Sealed
Playstation 5 (PS5) Bluray Disc System Console [...]
We usually ship within 24 hours of purchase."

Sample code below.  If I search for the text within the printout, I cannot find it.

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = 'www.ebay.com/itm/272037717929'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

it's probably because ebay is using javascript to load content into the page. A workout this problem would be using something [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) or selenium. I personally prefer the first option. It uses a chromium browser to actually get the page contents, hence loads javascript in the proccess